# level 2 headings with different styles

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a contract, and the first part of it are the "Main terms & conditions".  Then, the next part are the "Schedule".  Headings as below:

```
Main Terms & Conditions
    1.0 Definitions
    2.0 Schedules/Ordering Procedure
    3.0 ...
Schedule A
    Project Development Services
    ...
```

I would like the `1.0 Definitions`, etc. to appear as level 2 headers in the table of contents.  However, their styling is different to the `Project Development Services` heading.  Is it possible to have headings with different styles?  I tried to create a new style, but couldn't find any way to assign a level to a style, if that is even possible.

I am using Microsoft Word 2013.

Comment: Does selecting the text, right-clicking and picking *Styles* -> *Clear formatting* (or whatever exactly it may be called in Word 2013; I'm on 2010) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word's TOC field can gather content for the ToC from multiple sources.

One source is "paragraphs whose styles have the Outline Levels specified by the \o parameter, so e.g.

```
{ TOC \o "1-2" }
```

Would give you a ToC with Heading 1, heading 2, and any other paragraphs whose *styles* have Outline Levels 1 or 2. (In other words, the current Outline Level of the *paragraph* is not relevant, AFAIK). In this case, a paragraph whose style has Outline Level n will appear at level n in the ToC.

You can set the Outline Level of the style by finding the style name in the style gallery in the Home tab, right-clicking, then selecting Modify... Then click the Format... dropdown at the bottom left and click Paragraph. The item you need is the "Outline Level" (which you cannot change for the built-in Heading n styles). You may not be able to modify the Outline Level if there are no paragraphs with that style in the document.

Another source is a list of specified style names using the \t parameter. This allows you to use styles that have no Outline Level. So if you want Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3 at ToC levels 1, 2 and 3, and "mystyle1" to be shown at ToC level 2 and "mystyle2" to be at ToC level 3, you can use

```
{ TOC \o "1-3" \t "mystyle1,2,mystyle2,3" }
```

If your Regional Settings specify ";" as the list separator character, you need to use ";" instead of "," in there.

You can also use the \t parameter to modify the ToC level where you want paragraphs with style Heading 1 etc.

These features are available from the standard ToC insertion dialog box (References->Table of Contents->Custom table of contents...->Options)

Comment: What where you referring to by the `\o` notation?  I managed to do it by setting the Outline Level.

Comment: \o "1-2" means "include all the paragraphs whose _styles_ have (Outline) Levels 1 to 2". I'm not sure that's the information you are looking for, but I can see that my text could be a little clearer. All the switch arguments "\o", "\t" etc. are described in Microsoft's online help.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate styles with the desired formatting for the second level headings and set the `Outline Level` of both to `2`.

Comment: The OP "couldn't find any way to assign a level to a style," hence my lengthier explanation.