# Heading don't chaning color of line

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

It's possible set heading, that heading don't change color of line?
For expample, if I have 3 lines - red, green and blue and I set heading 1, all lines will heading 1 and will have other colors (first red, second green and third blue)?
So, how set heading, that don't change color of line? It's possible?

Thank you.

Edit: And I don't think this: [Word 2010: Create a Style without a font color](https://superuser.com/questions/360488/word-2010-create-a-style-without-a-font-color)
I think color of full one line, not one word.
I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, I solved it by variant in Related links by this: [level 2 headings with different styles](https://superuser.com/questions/676322/level-2-headings-with-different-styles?rq=1)
I did't know, that I can create 2 styles, which will be heading on the same level :).